# Vue - chunk-vendors.js gets very large

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, postman

I'm creating a vue app and want to use the postman-code-generators module in it.
The size of chunk-vendors.js is increased from 163KB to 9.5MB.
Is it possible to reduce the size?

Comment: Are you sure the environment is prod and not dev because in prod env the files are zipped but they aren't in dev env

Comment: Yes I use vue-cli and 'npm run build'. So it's definitive in production mode